# Expect send password to background job using a socket

Tags: sockets, connection, tcl, expect

In a little Expect application I want to start ssh-copy-id in parallel in order to decrease overall runtime. The application is working fine. The Expect main script starts for every ssh-copy-id a second Expect script that spawns and handles ssh-copy-id in/outputs as a background job. This is working fine.
For testing purposes I have passed the password via commandline. That is not acceptable in production. So I want to have ssh-copy-id.exp to get the password from main.exp using a Tcl socket. I have adapted examples from the Echo application in "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk" by Welch, Jones and Hobbs.

First I tested only the socket it in two separate Expect REPLs that worked. In both REPLs I sourced following code.

```
proc eserver {} {
    set sock [socket -server accept -myaddr localhost 0]
    # return port
    return [lindex [fconfigure $sock -sockname] 2]
}

set pw spasswort
proc accept {sock addr port} {
    global pw
    fconfigure $sock -buffering line
    fileevent $sock r [list sendpassword $sock $pw]
}

proc sendpassword {sock pw} {
    if {[eof $sock] || [catch {gets $sock line}]} {
        close $sock
        puts "Socket closed by eof or error"
        exit 1
    }
    switch $line {
        quit {
            puts $sock "Quitting connection"
            flush $sock
            close $sock
        }
        sendpw {
            puts $sock $pw
            flush $sock
        }
        # sende Antwort auf client request
        default { puts $sock $line }
    }
}

proc client {port} {
    set sock [socket -async localhost $port]
    fconfigure $sock -buffering line
    return $sock
}

proc req {port str} {
    puts $port $str
    flush $port
}

proc answer {port} {
    gets $port line
    flush $port
    puts stdout $line
    flush stdout
}
```

In REPL 1 I called:

```
eserver
```

In REPL2 I called:

```
set c [client $s]
req $c Test
answer $c

req $c TEST
answer $c # returns TEST -> ok

req $c sendpw
answer $c # returns password -> ok

req $c quit # disconnects -> ok
```

Output of "netstat -anp|grep expect when using REPL 1 and REPL 2

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36697         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3209/expect
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36697         127.0.0.1:42873         ESTABLISHED 3209/expect
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:42873         127.0.0.1:36697         ESTABLISHED 5163/expect
```

Then I added follwing code to main.exp:

```
proc eserver {} {
    set sock [socket -server accept -myaddr localhost 0]
    return [lindex [fconfigure $sock -sockname] 2]
}

proc accept {sock addr port} {
    global pw
    fconfigure $sock -buffering line
    fileevent $sock r [list sendpassword $sock $pw]
}

proc sendpassword {sock pw} {
    puts SENDPWD
    if {[eof $sock] || [catch {gets $sock line}]} {
        close $sock
        puts "Socket closed by eof or error"
        exit 1
    }
    switch $line {
        quit {
            puts $sock "Quitting connection"
            flush $sock
            close $sock
        }
        sendpw {
            puts $sock $pw
            flush $sock
        }
    }
}

# other definitions of procs
# some processing

set pw [passwd]
set serverport [eserver]
```

some more processing

```
exec ssh-copy-id.exp $host $user $serverport ...
```

$serverport is passed as parameter to ssh-copy-id.exp. It can be seen there with puts $serverport.

Following code I have added to ssh-copy-id.exp.

```
proc client {port} {
    puts $port
    puts CLIENT
    set sock [socket -async localhost $port]
    fconfigure $sock -buffering line
    return $sock
}

proc pw-read {sock} {
    puts $sock sendpw
    flush $sock
    gets $sock pw # This command hangs
    puts $pw
    write-file $statuslog [list "$host password received $pw"]
    puts $sock quit
    flush $sock
    return $pw
}

set clientsocket [client $serverport]
set pw [pw-read $clientsocket]
```

In proc pw-read the connection hangs. I have found a different output of "netstat -anp|grep expect":

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41186         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7378/expect
```

It seems to me that ssh-copy-id.exp does not establish a connection to server despite the server had been started and seems to listen.

Comment: I suspect the easiest fix may be to drop the `-async` socket option in the client proc.

Comment: I'm confused. Is `exec ssh-copy-id ` running the openssh program `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id`? If so, I understand it needs a hostname parameter, not a port number.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is:
exec ssh-copy-id.exp $host $user $serverport ...
and some additional parameters. The server portnuber is passed for the client procedure that connects to the server.

I have edited my post appropriately.

Comment: @Schelte Bron Removing -async did not change anything.

Comment: Perhaps it is to do with the Tcl socket comment: *Server sockets depend on the Tcl event mechanism to find out when new connections are opened. If the application doesn't enter the event loop, for example by invoking the vwait command or calling the C procedure Tcl_DoOneEvent, then no connections will be accepted.*  I'm not sure what your main loop is.